# Let $u\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then show that $u(0)=\iint u(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}\xi$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

It's possible that I'm missing a constant. Is there any way to directly prove this without invoking the Fourier Inversion theorem?

Comment: The result is missing a factor of $1/(2\pi)$.  Using distributions, note that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi x}\,d\xi=2\pi \delta(x)$.

Comment: Alternatively, one could write $u(0) = \int_{R^2} u(x) e^{-2\pi i x \cdot \xi} dx d\xi,$ if you do not wish to have the $2 \pi'$s out in front.

Comment: Why is that first statement true?

Comment: Any proof of this identity will be equivalent to proving the full Fourier inversion theorem (with very small modifications). I would focus on proving this theorem instead and get this particular results as a freebee.